# Set style attribute to "position : none" through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class which has an attribute **position** set as **absolute** I want to set it as **none** through **jquery**. Here is my class

```
.myClass {
   position:absolute;
}
```

Something like

```
$(myClass).css.("position", "none"`);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no `position: none` there a two possibilities:

You want to change to value of your `position`-attribute:

```
$('.myClass').css('position', 'fixed'); //or any other position-type
```

Possible values are:

- relative
- static
- inherit
- ...

or your intention was to hide a specific element:

```
$('.myClass').hide();
```

The above code  would be the same as `display: none;`

Answer (score 3):

Should be `position:static`, there is no `none` value. [**More about this here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Syntax)

### write this:

```
$('.myClass').css("position", "static"); // without the "." after "css"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".myClass").css("position", "static");
```

Comment: Please add more details to make it more useful for OP and other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `relative` if you do not want it to be `static/absolute/fixed` like,

```
$('.myClass').css("position", "relative");// remember myClass is not a variable in your case
//^^-------^ // here myClass is not a variable
```